VIsual Studio does not accept launch.json (pydebug)
I want to debug my python project using a remote debugger. So I created this launch.json file in .vscode folder of my project.
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python Debugger: Remote Attach",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "attach",
            "connect": {
                "host": "localhost",
                "port": 5678
            }                
        }
    ]
}

This is the code in my main.py file:
import debugpy
debugpy.listen(("0.0.0.0", 5678))
debugpy.wait_for_client()

But when I hit F5, I only get this dialog:

When I click on "Open 'launch.json', it opens the launch.json I created. No errors in file.
Any idea what could be wrong? The error message is really undescriptive 
